# Recieving data from other activity ArrayList [Java]

Tags: java, android, json, arraylist

i've been copy pasting alot of different code into my application (since i just started coding) and had some help from friends. But i don't want to keep bothering them.

My problem is that I have no clue how to open the ArrayList that is made on the bottom of the class into another class where he seperates the values into strings that later on will be passed on and finally should end in my Youtube API.

First the getter, this is the first activity (LesSelectionActivity.java)

```
    public void getLessons(){

    APIClient.get(url, new JsonHttpResponseHandler(){
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject object) {

            if (object != null) {
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonLesson = object.getJSONArray("sqllessons");
                   mLessons = new ArrayList<Lesson>();
                    for (int Index = 0; Index < jsonLesson.length(); Index++) {

                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonLes = jsonLesson.getJSONObject(Index);
                            Lesson lesson = new Lesson();

                            lesson.id = jsonLes.getInt("_id");
                            lesson.number = jsonLes.getInt("lesnumber");
                            lesson.videoId = jsonLes.getString("videourl");

                            System.out.println("data test: " + lesson.id);

                            mLessons.add(lesson);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return;
                }
            }
            setButtonLessons();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, JSONObject errorResponse) {
            Toast.makeText(LesSelectionActivity.this, "FAIL", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}

public  ArrayList<Lesson> getArrayLesson() {
    return mLessons;
}
```

I want it to open in my 'DataFiller'
It has no XML/Layout and should act as an adapter for the activity above.

```
public class DataFiller{

public static ArrayList<Lesson> readLessons(int given) {
    ArrayList<Lesson> lessons = new ArrayList<Lesson>();
    for (int i = (given * 25) - 24; i <= 25 * given; i++) {
        Lesson lesson = new Lesson();
        lesson.setId(i);
        lessons.add(lesson);
    }
    return lessons;
}
```

The script above is just an empty arraylist so i could test the listview. But this should be edited to the 'new' ArrayList from the other activity.

I'm not sure if you need it, but here's the Lesson model.

```
public class Lesson implements Serializable {

public int id;
public int number;
public String videoId;

public Lesson() {
}

public Lesson(Lesson lesson) {
    number = lesson.number;
    id = lesson.id;
    videoId = lesson.videoId;
}

public int getId() { return id; }

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getVideoId() {
    return videoId;
}

public void setVideoId(String videoId) {
    this.videoId = videoId;
}

public int getNumber() {
    return number;
}

public void setNumber(int number) {
    this.number = number;
}
```

I've been searching this entire day for an awnser how to use that ArrayList, but mayby due to lack of knowledge that I'm not using the right search terms.

PS. How did you learn data transfers (like JSON and ArrayLists). Just by doing and trying? or did you had an online course or something? I've tried the basic Android Studio course but lost interest after they stuck to long on the basics. But I noticed how farther I'd get with this app, the more I'm stuck on (what I think are) simple pieces of coding?

Comment: Ok so first you will have to put the whole context on this, because I dont really understand what is the first class and what is the second, but I will suppose the first is an activity and the second your adapter, what You have to do is after getting your arraylist, pass it into your Adapter, HOW? create a method to set it or pass it via the constructor itself, if you need to pass it from one ACTIVITY to Another Activity the you will have to do it via the intent, please explain a little more the context of your code and I will be grateful to help your.

Comment: it seems that first class has a field in which you can save the Arraylist. There is also the method getArrayLesson() you define that return just the array you want. Can you paste more code ?

Comment: I'd like to show you the code but I don't know which code you are looking for. The getArrayLesson() is being called on the setButtonLessons but that's not working yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the ArrayList that you filled in the getLessons() method just call the class and the getArrayLesson() method like this:

```
 public class DataFiller{

     public ArrayList<Lesson> readLessons() {  
         return LesSelectionActivity.getArrayLesson();
    }
 }
```

Comment: I tried this, but when i did, my return mLessons now gives an error "Non-static field 'mLessons' cannot be referenced from a static context".

Comment: change  public static ArrayList<Lesson> readLessons()  to  public ArrayList<Lesson> readLessons()

Comment: If I remove the static, the "return LesSelectionActivity.getArrayLesson();" does not work anymore and gives the error "Non-static method 'getArrayLesson()' cannot be referenced from a static context".
To me, this makes no sense, because when i alt enter it advises me to make the getArrayLesson in the first class (LesSelectionActivity) public static again.

Comment: The method .getArrayLesson() wasn't static? change it to be static

Comment: If i make it static, the return mLessons; will say "Non-static field 'mLessons' cannot be referenced from a static context" again...
 mLessons is in the first/top activity in this thread and is an array of lesson.id, lesson.number and lesson.videoId.

Comment: Somehow it works, i don't know what i did, but suddenly all the errors are gone. To bad i still don't know why it suddenly works.